# sorting an alphanumeric column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table 'MyTable' with the following the column, ID varchar(50).

```
ID
----------
10
100
700-6 0110B512
700-6 0110B513
700-8 0110B512
700-9 0110B512
```

I need to sort this column with the output

```
ID
----------
10
100
700-6 0110B512
700-8 0110B512
700-9 0110B512
700-6 0110B513
```

Please help!!

I have tried like this but the output is not as desired.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY
Case    
When IsNumeric(ID) = 1 then LEFT(Replicate('0',101) + ID, 100) 
When IsNumeric(ID) = 0 then RIGHT(Replicate('0',101) + ID, 100) 
Else ID  
END
ASC
```

Comment: does the Isnumeric(id) = 1 get hit at all? the field ia varchar?

Comment: It will get hit for 10 and 100!!

Comment: Do you have at maximum three digits? So 1, 10, 100, 700 BUT NOT 1000, 2000, 10000?

Comment: It will be always be 3 digits and most of the time 700 only.

Comment: @vijay in mysql if you just write select * from table_name orderby column_name then its automatically sorts,i do not know whether it works in sql server 2005 or not.Just check it

Comment: `LEFT(Replicate('0',101) + ID, 100) ` this is wrong... You create a string of 101x0 + ID and take the first 100 characters... You'll only take 100x0! You probably meant `RIGHT`.

Comment: Vijay i found a similar issue, look at this link for ideas am sure that will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862147/sorting-varchar-column-with-alphanumeric-entries?rq=1

Comment: I have achived by spliting strings and sorting.But i wanted to know is there anything which is more generilistic ??

Comment: After Alphabet B or  Anyone eLSE it always 3 characheter or more is

Comment: @vijay Sorry, but I have to vote for close as unclear until you describe the exact sorting algorithm you want. There are multiple algorithms that will give the result you give as desired.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The table MyTable is actually a temp table in a stored procedure.I have performing some query and inserting the resultset into it.And then performing a sorting on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t table(id varchar(50))
INSERT @t values ('10')
INSERT @t values('100')
INSERT @t values('700-6 0110B512')
INSERT @t values('700-6 0110B513')
INSERT @t values('700-8 0110B512')
INSERT @t values('700-9 0110B512')

SELECT * 
FROM @t 
ORDER BY cast(left(id, 3) as int), stuff(id, 1, 6, ''), substring(id, 5,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fixed leading/trailing integers, I think this is the simplest it could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
ORDER BY LEFT(id,3) ,RIGHT(id,3) ,ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc987/7/0)

Could cast either portion as `INT` if needed, not clear from sample.

Comment: Puts 20 after 100, but there's nothing in the question saying that's wrong, so... :)