# Alphanumeric and Numeric sorting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I need to apply sorting on Alphanumeric and Numeric sorting.

Example:

```
319,
519, 
620, 
1154, 
1195, 
319lov,
319, 
620lov
```

I need result like:

```
319,
319,
319lov,
519, 
620, 
620lov,
1154, 
1195,
```

I have applied following code to sort:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM TableName
ORDER BY CAST(CASE
                 WHEN Name LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' THEN LEFT(Name ,4)
                 WHEN Name LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]%' THEN LEFT(Name ,3)
                 ELSE NULL 
              END AS INT)
```

Got result like:

```
319,
319lov,
319,
519, 
620,
620lov, 
1154, 
1195,
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862147/sorting-varchar-column-with-alphanumeric-entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862147/sorting-varchar-column-with-alphanumeric-entries)

Comment: after `AS INT)` just add `, Name`

Comment: @JamieD77 It is working good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM t 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(name, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name+'z')-1)),name;
```

You order by all the numbers up to the first non number,the letter is in there to treat all strings the same.

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49247/3)

Comment: Nope,[counterexample](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/427747).